# Patterns for simulating optional "out" parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, out-parameters

I'm translating an API from C to C#, and one of the functions allocates a number of related objects, some of which are optional. The C version accepts several pointer parameters which are used to return integer handles to the objects, and the caller can pass `NULL` for some of the pointers to avoid allocating those objects:

```
void initialize(int *mainObjPtr, int *subObjPtr, int *anotherSubObjPtr);

initialize(&mainObj, &subObj, NULL);
```

For the C# version, the obvious translation would use `out` parameters instead of pointers:

```
public static void Initialize(out int mainObj, out int subObj,
    out int anotherSubObj);
```

... but this leaves no way to indicate which objects are unwanted. Are there any well-known examples of C# APIs doing something similar that I could imitate? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't be using `int` for the objects anyway - they should be references, i.e. `out SomeMainType mainObj, out SomSubType subObj`. That done, you can then use overloads, but this would be ungainly.

A better approach would be to return something with the 3 objects - a custom type, or in .NET 4.0 maybe a tuple.

Something like:

```
class InitializeResult {
    public SomeMainType MainObject {get;set;}
    public SomeSubType SubObject {get;set;}
    ...
}
public static InitializeResult Initialize() {...}
```

---

Re-reading it, it looks like the caller is also passing data *in* (even if only null / not-null), so `out` was *never* the right option. Maybe a flags enum?

```
[Flags]
public enum InitializeOptions {
    None = 0, Main = 1, Sub = 2, Foo = 4, Bar = 8, ..
}
```

and call:

```
var result = Initialize(InitializeOptions.Main | InitializeOptions.Sub);
var main = result.MainObject;
var sub = result.SubObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest translation would be using `ref` and `IntPtr`

```
public static void Initialize(ref IntPtr mainObj, ref IntPtr subObj,
ref IntPtr anotherSubObj)
```

and specifying `IntPtr.Zero` for unwanted values.

But for me the question arises why you want to resemble the API that close unless you are trying to figure out a P/Invoke signature. Assuming `mainObj` has  accessible references to both sub object something like

```
public static MainObjectType Initialize(bool initSubObj, bool initAnotherSubObj)
```

appears to be a much cleaner solution to me. In .NET 4 you can even make the boolean arguments optional or simulate this with overloads in pre .NET 4. If there are no accessible references to the sub objects you could return a simple container type holding the references.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide overloads of the method that don't take out parameters, and call the overload that does :

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    int mainObj;
    int subObj;
    int anotherSubObj;
    Initialize(out mainObj, out subObj, out anotherSubObj);
    // discard values of out parameters...
}

public static void Initialize(out int mainObj, out int subObj, out int anotherSubObj)
{
    // Whatever...
}
```

But as suggested by Marc, you should probably consider using a more object oriented approach...

Comment: Unfortunately I need to avoid allocating the unwanted objects at all: first because some of the objects will be visible on screen as soon as they're created, and second because this is an interface for an unmanaged library, so anything I allocate will eventually need to be freed explicitly. (The unmanaged part is also why the objects are referred to with handles rather than .NET types.)